# Converting Gregorian date to Hijri date

Tags: javascript, date, gregorian-calendar, date-conversion, hijri

How do you convert Gregorian dates to Islamic Hijri dates using JavaScript?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
function gmod(n,m){
return ((n%m)+m)%m;
}

function kuwaiticalendar(adjust){
var today = new Date();
if(adjust) {
    adjustmili = 1000*60*60*24*adjust; 
    todaymili = today.getTime()+adjustmili;
    today = new Date(todaymili);
}
day = today.getDate();
month = today.getMonth();
year = today.getFullYear();
m = month+1;
y = year;
if(m<3) {
    y -= 1;
    m += 12;
}

a = Math.floor(y/100.);
b = 2-a+Math.floor(a/4.);
if(y<1583) b = 0;
if(y==1582) {
    if(m>10)  b = -10;
    if(m==10) {
        b = 0;
        if(day>4) b = -10;
    }
}

jd = Math.floor(365.25*(y+4716))+Math.floor(30.6001*(m+1))+day+b-1524;

b = 0;
if(jd>2299160){
    a = Math.floor((jd-1867216.25)/36524.25);
    b = 1+a-Math.floor(a/4.);
}
bb = jd+b+1524;
cc = Math.floor((bb-122.1)/365.25);
dd = Math.floor(365.25*cc);
ee = Math.floor((bb-dd)/30.6001);
day =(bb-dd)-Math.floor(30.6001*ee);
month = ee-1;
if(ee>13) {
    cc += 1;
    month = ee-13;
}
year = cc-4716;


wd = gmod(jd+1,7)+1;

iyear = 10631./30.;
epochastro = 1948084;
epochcivil = 1948085;

shift1 = 8.01/60.;

z = jd-epochastro;
cyc = Math.floor(z/10631.);
z = z-10631*cyc;
j = Math.floor((z-shift1)/iyear);
iy = 30*cyc+j;
z = z-Math.floor(j*iyear+shift1);
im = Math.floor((z+28.5001)/29.5);
if(im==13) im = 12;
id = z-Math.floor(29.5001*im-29);

var myRes = new Array(8);

myRes[0] = day; //calculated day (CE)
myRes[1] = month-1; //calculated month (CE)
myRes[2] = year; //calculated year (CE)
myRes[3] = jd-1; //julian day number
myRes[4] = wd-1; //weekday number
myRes[5] = id; //islamic date
myRes[6] = im-1; //islamic month
myRes[7] = iy; //islamic year

return myRes;
}
function writeIslamicDate(adjustment) {
var wdNames = new Array("Ahad","Ithnin","Thulatha","Arbaa","Khams","Jumuah","Sabt");
var iMonthNames = new Array("Muharram","Safar","Rabi'ul Awwal","Rabi'ul Akhir",
"Jumadal Ula","Jumadal Akhira","Rajab","Sha'ban",
"Ramadan","Shawwal","Dhul Qa'ada","Dhul Hijja");
var iDate = kuwaiticalendar(adjustment);
var outputIslamicDate = wdNames[iDate[4]] + ", " 
+ iDate[5] + " " + iMonthNames[iDate[6]] + " " + iDate[7] + " AH";
return outputIslamicDate;
}
```

This converts **current** computer date to hijri. And with a little modification you can achieve that this snippet change any date to islamic

```
document.write(writeIslamicDate(1));
```

Taken from [This site](http://www.al-habib.info/islamic-calendar/hijricalendartext.htm)

Comment: thank you for the fast reply, i will try and use this function.. =D

Comment: Excellent, can you please tell me what this adjustment / adjust variable is used for??

Comment: "Adjust" variable is used to correct the shift in Hijri dates which occurs because of variable moon status and visibility on different months.

Comment: Please see here to convert any Islamic calendar to Gregorian Date without using libraries or complex formulas:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222556/how-to-convert-any-of-the-5-islamic-hijri-calendars-dates-to-any-of-18-world

Answer (score 6):

If you need only the year of Hijri date converted from Gregorian date (Miladi date) you can simply write this equation in javascript:

```
var GregorianYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
var HijriYear = Math.round((GregorianYear - 622) * (33 / 32));
```

you can use this simple equation in the footer in master page like
كل الحقوق محفوطة لـ ... ©

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write((new Date()).getFullYear())</script> م - <script type="text/javascript">var y = (new Date()).getFullYear();var h = Math.round((y - 622) * (33 / 32));document.write(h)</script> هـ
```

you will get:
كل الحقوق محفوطة لـ ... © 2014 م - 1435 هـ

you can also use C# embedded in asp page as:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.Year %> - <%=  Math.Round((DateTime.Now.Year - 622) * 1.03125) %>
```

will return : 2014 - 1436

Finally, if you need to convert to UmAlQura date, simply try this line of code:

```
let _date = new Date('7/10/2019').toLocaleDateString('ar-SA').format('DD/MM/YYYY');

console.log(_date);
```

will return : ٧‏/١١‏/١٤٤٠ هـ

Update (2021-10-11) : If you need a more precise equation you have to know the current day of solar year by this formula :

```
var now = new Date();
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - start;
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var dayOfYear = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
```

Then you can get the Hijri year by this formula:

```
HijriYear = ((GregorianYear-621.5643)*365.24225 + dayOfYear) / 354.36707
```

Where :

**365.24225** is the number of days in solar year.

**354.36707** is the number of days in lunar year.

**621.5643** is the exact Gregorian date of Hijra (start date of Hijri date)

HijriYear = ((2021-621.5643)*365.24225 + 284) / 354.36707 = **1,443.18444**

So the current Hijri year is **1443** by using `Math.floor(HijriYear)` function.

Also you can use the fraction :

```
var hijriDayOfYear  = (HijriYear - Math.floor(HijriYear)) * 354.36707
```

**0.18444** multiplied by **354.36707** to get the number of days in Hijri calendar :

0.18444 * 354.36707 = **65.3**  : the number of day in this current Hijri year

`Math.ceil(hijriDayOfYear / 29.530589) = 3` number of current Hijri month

`Math.floor(hijriDayOfYear % 29.530589) = 6 ± 1` number of day in this Hijri month

Finally to summarize all of previous just use the following JS code:

```
var now = new Date()
var dayOfYear = Math.floor((new Date() - new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
var hijriDate = ((now.getFullYear()-621.5643)*365.24225 + dayOfYear) / 354.36707
var hijriYear = Math.floor(hijriDate)
var hijriMonth = Math.ceil((hijriDate - Math.floor(hijriDate)) * 354.36707 / 29.530589)
var hijriDay = Math.floor((hijriDate - Math.floor(hijriDate)) * 354.36707 % 29.530589)
    
console.log(`${hijriYear}/${hijriMonth}/${hijriDay}`)
```

console output sample : 1443/3/6

General JavaScript Function to convert datetime to Hijri date:

```
function GetHijriDate(dateTime) {    
    var dayOfYear = Math.floor((dateTime - new Date(dateTime.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
    var hijriDate = ((dateTime.getFullYear() - 621.5643) * 365.24225 + dayOfYear) / 354.36707
    var hijriYear = Math.floor(hijriDate)
    var hijriMonth = Math.ceil((hijriDate - Math.floor(hijriDate)) * 354.36707 / 29.530589)
    var hijriDay = Math.floor((hijriDate - Math.floor(hijriDate)) * 354.36707 % 29.530589)
    return [hijriYear, hijriMonth , hijriDay]
}
```

In C# :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the hijri date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date">The date.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int[] GetHijriDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var yearOfHijra = 621.5643f;
        var daysInSolarYear = 365.24225f;
        var daysInLunarYear = 354.36707f;
        var daysInLunarMonth = 29.53058f;

        var hijriDate = ((date.Year - yearOfHijra) * daysInSolarYear  + date.DayOfYear) / daysInLunarYear;
        var hijriYear = (int)Math.Floor(hijriDate);
        var hijriMonth = (int)Math.Ceiling((hijriDate - Math.Floor(hijriDate)) * daysInLunarYear / daysInLunarMonth);
        var hijriDay = (int)Math.Floor((hijriDate - Math.Floor(hijriDate)) * daysInLunarYear % daysInLunarMonth);

        int[] hijriDateRes = new int[3];
        hijriDateRes[0] = hijriYear;
        hijriDateRes[1] = hijriMonth;
        hijriDateRes[2] = hijriDay;

        return hijriDateRes;
    }
```

Or Simply :

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('ar-SA'))
```

'٥‏/٣‏/١٤٤٣ هـ'

Comment: This formula will give an error of -11 days to +2 days (depending on the year) from the correct Hijri Date based on the Umalqura Calendar.

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei : Thank you for your comment, you can review the final Update (2021-10-11), we add more precise equation with simple code in both JS & C#, as well as the Umalqura is just a selection date from fixed static array with limited predefined dates.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the approximate formula to convert from Hijri to Gregorian?

Comment: Please see here to convert any Islamic calendar to Gregorian Date without using libraries or complex formulas:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222556/how-to-convert-any-of-the-5-islamic-hijri-calendars-dates-to-any-of-18-world

Answer (score 6):

Checkout my library [hijrah-date](https://github.com/msarhan/hijrah-date) which is a Javascript date in the Hijrah calendar system.

It also supports Hijrah to Gregorian and Gregorian to Hijrah conversion. In addition to date formatting.

Comment: Please see here to convert any Islamic calendar to Gregorian Date without using libraries or complex formulas:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222556/how-to-convert-any-of-the-5-islamic-hijri-calendars-dates-to-any-of-18-world

Answer (score 4):

The safest is to use the built-in javascript [Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

Here is an example of the 4 output formats in the Islamic Hijri Calendar of today's date.

Also examples of extracting the year and months separately under different formats.

```js
let myFormat = 'en-u-ca-islamic-umalqura-nu-latn'; // use islamic-umalqura calendar (most modern)
let myDate   = new Date(Date.now());  // today's date
let output   = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(myFormat,{dateStyle:'full'}).format(myDate);
console.log("Full format   : "+output);

output   = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(myFormat,{dateStyle:'long'}).format(myDate);
console.log("Long format   : "+output);

output   = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(myFormat,{dateStyle:'medium'}).format(myDate);
console.log("Medium format : "+output);

output   = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(myFormat,{dateStyle:'short'}).format(myDate);
console.log("Short format (m/d/yyyy): "+output);

console.log("=".repeat(50));

let yearFull = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(myFormat,{year:'numeric'}).format(myDate);
console.log("The full year     : "+yearFull);
console.log("The year number   : " +(+yearFull.split(" ")[0]));

let monthLong = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(myFormat,{month:'long'}).format(myDate);
let monthShort = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(myFormat,{month:'short'}).format(myDate);
let monthNum = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(myFormat,{month:'numeric'}).format(myDate);
let month2 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(myFormat,{month:'2-digit'}).format(myDate);
console.log("The long month    : "+monthLong);
console.log("The short month   : "+monthShort);
console.log("The month number  : "+monthNum);
console.log("The month 2 digits: "+month2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript to convert the date, you could use `Intl` ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)) as following:

```js
a = new Date();
localeFormat= 'ar-SA-islamic-umalqura';
Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeFormat).format(a)
```